Accessing Selection of Values in Variant Data Type at a Specific Index in Excel VBA
I am trying to store these selection of values in a Variant data type in a variable 'stat'.
The value '1' in cell is referenced 'BodyStart'.

I am then looking to access a particular value at a specific index for example, to return the value 5, stat(2) should give me the answer based on 0-index but this isn't working sadly. Here is the code:
Dim LR As Long, stat() As Variant
Range("BodyStart").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
stat = Selection.Value

MsgBox stat(2)

I am getting subscript out of range error
Your help will be much appreciated.
Thank You.

You have created a 2-dimentional array and you are trying to read it using only one parameter.

MsgBox stat(3, 1) would return the 5.  stat = Range("BodyStart").CurrentRegion.Value2 would work to place the range into an array rather than all that Select stuff.   How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA

Use the Locals window to view the status of your variables (can be opened through the View menu) and use F8 to step through your code line by line.  That will then show how the values are stored within the array.

Thanks everyone for the help. Much appreciated.
